# Viewport size in Firefox

Tags: firefox

When I resize the element inspector in Chromium (docked to the right) I get a constantly-updating viewport size appearing at the top right of the web page (or top left of the element inspector). Is there any way I can get the Firefox element inspector to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a similar function is available. It is not visible by default (I think) though. To enable it, go to developer tools settings and enable “Toggle rulers for the page” in the “Available Toolbox Buttons” section. A new button will appear in the upper right corner of the dev tools:

[image: ruler button]

When you enable this feature, translucent rulers will show up as well as the viewport dimensions:

[image: rules enabled view]

I’m not aware of a way to get this without the rulers. Of course, Responsive Design Mode (the button right of ruler button in the screenshot above) also shows the viewport size, but it’s different from regular browsing.

Comment: Aha! That's perfect, thank you :-)